# Prove the asymptotic probability of numbers being relative prime equals $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

For a number theory problem, I'm trying to prove that the asymptotic probability of numbers being relative prime equals $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$. Unfortunately, I'm a bit stuck at the following equality.

$$\frac{n^2}{2}\sum_{d=1}^n \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}-\frac{n}{2}\sum_{d=1}^n\frac{\mu(d)}{d} \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \phi(k) \leq \frac{n^2}{2}\sum_{d=1}^n \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}+\frac{n}{2}\sum_{d=1}^n\frac{\mu(d)}{d} $$

Where $\mu(d)$ is the Möbius arithmetic function and $\phi(k)$ is the Euler $\phi$ function.

Now I know that 
$$|\sum_{d=1}^n\frac{\mu(d)}{d}| \leq \sum_{d=1}^n\frac{1}{d} = 1+\sum_{d=2}^n\frac{1}{d} \leq 1+\log{n},$$
However, what I don't quite get is why it then should follow that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=2}^n\phi(k)}{n(n-1)} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{d=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}.$$

Any help on why this is the case?

Comment: Divide the inequality by $n(n-1)\sim n^2$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Is it also the case that because we take $\lim_{n \to \infty}$, the $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\frac{n}{2}\sum_{d=1}^n \frac{\mu(d)}{d}$ term vanishes?